# Removing Duplicated Values

Tags: date, duplicates, data-cleaning

After data cleaning and aggregation I was left with a data table like this:

```
df
id d1        v1  d2        v2  d3        v3  d4        v4
1  1-1-2018  1   1-1-2018  1   1-1-2018  1   1-1-2018  1
2  1-1-2018  1   1-2-2018  2   1-2-2018  2   1-2-2018  2
3  1-1-2018  1   1-2-2018  2   1-3-2018  3   1-3-2018  3
4  1-1-2018  1   1-2-2018  2   1-3-2018  3   1-4-2018  4
```

I am trying to remove any values from a column in the above data frame that are duplicates of earlier columns.

I have already tried:

```
df$v2[df$v1 == df$v2] <- NA
```

this removed all of the values from the v2 column

I want my data frame to look like this at the end:

```
df
id d1        v1  d2        v2  d3        v3  d4        v4
1  1-1-2018  1   NA        NA  NA        NA  NA        NA
2  1-1-2018  1   1-2-2018  2   NA        NA  NA        NA
3  1-1-2018  1   1-2-2018  2   1-3-2018  3   NA        NA
4  1-1-2018  1   1-2-2018  2   1-3-2018  3   1-4-2018  4
```

Comment: What programming language or tool are you using? Please tag your question accordingly. It will vastly improve your chances of attracting people who know to your question, and thus the chances of qualified answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try df[...condition here...]$column <- NA

Or with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[d1 == d2, v1 := NA]
```